# Is there a way to define a function for different std::array without defining a template function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates, c++11

I am playing around with `std::array` and want to learn about the use-cases and what one can do and what not.

So, I defined myself a bunch of similar `array`-types and now want to defines a function that works on all of them.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>            // accumulate, iota
#include <iostream>

using January  = std::array<int,31>;
using February = std::array<int,28>;
using March    = std::array<int,31>;
using April    = std::array<int,30>;  // ...more Months..

int main() {
    /* init */
    Januar   jan; std::iota(begin(jan), end(jan), 1); // 1..31
    February feb; std::iota(begin(feb), end(feb), 1);
    March    mar; std::iota(begin(mar), end(mar), 1);
    April    apr; std::iota(begin(apr), end(apr), 1);

    /* sum them up */
    int all = sum(jan) + sum(feb) + sum(mar) + sum(apr); // sum()-calls
}
```

So, the task is to define a function `sum` that can work on all of the `array`-types. But since all those types are different I can think only of a function template.

```
template<typename ARRAY>
int sum(const ARRAY& arr) {
    return std::accumulate(begin(arr), end(arr), 0);
}
```

For those C++-programmers who are scared of writing templates, **is there any template-less solution**? How to write **one single function** that works for **different `array`-types**?

Comment: *ehem*. Yes, I cout but: *"...and want to learn about the use-cases and what one can do and what not"*

Comment: *"that works for different `array`-types"* I interpret this as *different lengths*, not different *`value_type`s*. Well you essentially have the same options as for raw arrays, as the different `std::array`-specializations are unrelated. For example, you can write an `accumulate` function that takes two `int*` and an `int` as parameters (effectively `std::accumulate<int*, int>`).

Comment: @towi do you have to use `sum(array)` syntax, or would `sum(array.data(), array.data()+array.size())` be acceptable?

Comment: @yakk: It would be acceptable. But my obvious try would be a template too, with two iterator arguments, i.e. `template<typename IT> int sum(IT begin, IT end);`. Alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to implement `sum` without templates, but I wouldn't argue that any of them are "better".  Some worse ways I can think of:

1) macros.

```
int sumarray(int arr[], int asz) ;

#define sum(XXX) sumarray(& XXX[0], XXX.size)
```

2) inheritance.

Define an abstract base class that all the months inherit from in addition to `std::array` and define virtual interface to sum().

3) specialization/polymorphism

```
int sum(const std::array<int,28>& arr) { ... }
int sum(const std::array<int,29>& arr) { ... }
int sum(const std::array<int,30>& arr) { ... }
int sum(const std::array<int,31>& arr) { ... }
```

4) type erasure/pimpl

Left as an exercise to the reader (but uses templates down inside).

Comment: Very good points! 1) The macro-solution can be done macro-less, too, which I like. I didn't think of it (back to C, yay!). 2) Overkill, and is a good example for my "I want to learn ... what arrays can *not* do". 3) I really meant a single function. 4) Same as with inheritance, I guess. Well thanks, your input really gave me ideas about what arrays can/should be used for and what not.

Answer (score 2):

I have a utility class that takes a range that stores data in contiguous memory, and returns a range view into it.

```
template<typename T>
struct contig_range_view {
  T* m_begin;
  T* m_end;
  contig_range_view(T* b, T* e):m_begin(b), m_end(e) {}
  contig_range_view():m_begin(nullptr), n_end(nullptr) {}
  contig_range_view(contig_range_view&& o):m_begin(o.m_begin), n_end(o.m_end) {}
  contig_range_view(contig_range_view& o):m_begin(o.m_begin), n_end(o.m_end) {}
  template<typename T, typename A>
  contig_range_view( std::vector<T,A>& v ):m_begin(v.data()), m_end(v.data()+v.size()) {}
  template<typename T, std::size_t N>
  contig_range_view( std::array<T,N>& a ):m_begin(a.data()), m_end(a.data()+a.size()) {}
  template<typename T, std::size_t N>
  contig_range_view( T(&a)[N] ):m_begin(&a[0]), m_end(&a[0]+N) {}
  T* begin() { return m_begin; }
  T const* begin() const { return m_begin; }
  T* end() { return m_end; }
  T const* end() const { return m_end; }
  std::size_t size() const { return m_end - m_begin; }
};
```

with a specialization for `T const` that takes `std::vector<T,A> const&v` but blocks `std::vector<T,A>&&` (etc).

Then, you write your function as taking:

```
int sum( contig_range_view<int> values ) {
  int retval = 0;
  for( int v : values )
    retval += v;
  return retval;
}
```

and your `sum` function is not a template function.

The technique used here is a type erased view into the container.  It happens to be ridiculously efficient as well.

There are still `template`s used in the constructors to `contig_range_view`, but they are hidden from the end-programmer user.

A side benefit is this lets you write really generic array-processing code that doesn't have to live in a header file.  It can process `C` arrays, `std::vector`s and `std::array`s without breaking a sweat.  In theory, knowing the length of the content to be processed at compile time can make the body of the function slightly more efficient, but that is about the only loss.

The blocking of `rvalue` binding is because a view into a container that goes away instantly is questionable, especially a non-const view into said container.  Blocking it on the `contig_range_view<const T>` case is questionable: I could go either way.

Comment: A point for implementing type erasure for this class, but the OP said that there was some concern about templates being any part of the solution.  (not sure why).  By the way, you know your move constructor does a copy instead, not that there are any resources involved or anything.

Comment: @woolstar The goal is to make writing the `sum` function not require writing any `template`s, just using them.  Clearly working with `std::array<int, 27>` involves working with *some* `template`s (namely `std::array`), but it does not require writing them.  The rvalue constructor exists because a copy-from-`const` is illegal, but a copy-from-rvalue is perfectly ok.  Without it, a function returning a `contig_range_view` would not be able to assign to another `contig_range_view`.  It is not a `move`, it is a `copy` from rvalue.

Comment: @woolstar and @Yakk: Yes and no. I want to learn what arrays can practically be used for. And although I would not presume to write a good general wrapper like `contig_range_view` myself I would like to file this under "there is a potential case for the use of arrays". Until now I found it quite awkward to have all newly starting C++ programmers have to learn templates on their second day. C++11 is supposed to be easier to learn ;-) Therefore I take with me `array` alone might not be "it", yet, but given the right framework, it is practical.

Comment: @towi `array` is juwt a way to get a slightly less quirky version of the C-style `int x[N]` syntax.   It is not the `array` to end all `array`s, just better than what we had before in a few small ways (like the ability to return from a function). Ranged based helpers are coming in 14 or 17 I suspect.

Comment: @yakk: Which ranged-based helpers exactly? Which ones are in queue? Are there any in the current C++1y draft (aka C++14)?

Comment: I think you have a typo: `n_end` instead of `m_end`; and I'm not sure why you don't use `=default` for some of the ctors.

Comment: `contig_range_view(contig_range_view& o)` I'm not sure why you require mutability here; the class has pointer semantics and `contig_range_view<T>` is already unrelated to `contig_range_view<T const>` (IMHO it should be a relationship similar to `iterator` and `const_iterator`, where there's even a conversion from the former to the latter).

Comment: @DyP the idea was that a `const contig_range_view<T>` would be a view on `const` data: possibly unwise.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not quite without templates, this strikes some middle ground between the horrible type-unsafe pointer abuse and the template you gave:

```
template< size_t size >
int sum( const std::array< int, size > &a ) {
    return std::accumulate( begin(a), end(a), 0 );
}
```

Comment: You are right of course, and I implemented both versions -- the type-unsafe one was just my first. You get a +1 for pointing that error-ish thing out.

Answer (score 1):

As a completely different method, we can exploit the fact that our data is stored in contiguous memory.  And use raw pointers as iterators.

We define `sum` as follows:

```
int sum( int const* begin, int const* end );
```

And implement it like this:

```
int sum( int const* begin, int const* end ) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int const* it = begin; it != end; ++it ) {
    result += *it;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now, our use of `sum` looks like:

```
int some = sum(jan.data(), jan.data()+jan.size());
```

etc.  This has the advantage of looking and coding like C++ `<algorithms>` but being pointer-based, it isn't written as a `template`.